# Enable DNS forwarding Bind9

Tags: ubuntu, dns, bind9

I've a bind9 in Ubuntu. It is working fine resolving DNS names for my lab domain xutilab.local, but it is not working if I request something like [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

This is the named.conf.options file:

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
    // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
    // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

    // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
    // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
    // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
    // the all-0's placeholder.
     allow-query {
        any;
    };

    forwarders {
            8.8.8.8;
    };

    //========================================================================
    // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
    // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
    //========================================================================
    dnssec-validation auto;

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    notify yes;
    allow-transfer { any; };
```

Any missing option here?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found that the issue was in my router, which has an option related to security in DNS. Disabling it, Bind9 is able to forward the requests ok with the current configuration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inside this block (options), try add:

```
allow-recursion { any; };
allow-query { any; };
allow-query-cache { any; };
```